# Replicating a figure in Latex

Tags: floats, diagrams, arrows

I am a beginner in Latex and i need to replicate the following image, but I am having trouble doing it and I don't know what packages I need in order to replicate it properly. I tried the TikZ package however i couldn't seem to get a similar result. Can anyone please help? Thank you!

[image: ACE Model of Behavioral Genetics]

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you show us what you tried in TikZ? Even a starting point shows effort on your part and will put us quickly on the road to a solution. :-)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex]
\begin{scope}
\node[circle,draw] (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node[right=7mm of A,circle,draw] (C) {C};
\node[right=7mm of C,circle,draw] (E) {E};
\node[below=12mm of C,draw,inner sep=1ex] (Twin 1) {Twin 1};
\foreach \X/\x in {A/a,C/c,E/e} \draw[->] (\X) --node[left] {\x} (Twin 1);
\node[above=5mm of A,anchor=south west]{$\text{MZ}=1$, $\text{DZ}=0.5$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\node[circle,draw] (Ap) at (0,0) {A};
\node[right=7mm of Ap,circle,draw] (Cp) {C};
\node[right=7mm of Cp,circle,draw] (Ep) {E};
\node[below=12mm of Cp,draw,inner sep=1ex] (Twin 2) {Twin 2};
\foreach \X/\x in {A/a,C/c,E/e} \draw[->] (\X p) --node[left] {\x} (Twin 2);
\node[above=5mm of Ap,anchor=south west]{$\text{MZ}=1$, $\text{DZ}=1$};
\end{scope}
\draw[<->] (A) to[out=40,in=140] (Ap);
\draw[<->] (C) to[out=40,in=140] (Cp);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Fine tunings are left as exercise. If you need more information, you must read [pgfmanual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much @skpblack ! I will do some fine-tuning and maybe some additions. Thanks again!